# Replacing specific links in text

Tags: java, regex

I'm using java. I have a text and in this text has few links. Some of them link to specific websites, these links will not change. the rest doesn't and i want to replace these links by a link.
I used to `replaceAll()` method with:

```
String input = "my text";
String regex = "<a href=\"[^\"]+\">[^<]+</a>";
String output = input.replaceAll(regex, "<a href=\"myweb.com\">my web</a>");
```

But it replaces all links in my text and i don't know how to ask it just replaces some links.
How can i do my purpose? Thanks
Updated:
`input` is just a article within content and few links.

Comment: Your regex is not aware of what should be replaced by `myweb.com` so you have to add it to it.

Comment: give us a proper input text in your question

Comment: There should be some thing common in URL which you do not want to replace

Comment: String output = input.replaceAll(regex, "<a href=myweb.com>.*?</a>");

Comment: @SSP input text is just a article with content and few links.

Comment: @A4L can you give me a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
<a href=\"[^\"]+\">[^<]+</a>
```

It would not be possible since `[^\"]+` will match **any charachter** which is not a `"`

You could try the following regex

```
<a href=\".*(foo\\.com|bar\\.org).*\">[^<]+</a>
```

With this sample text

```
static String input = "my text\r\n" +
        "Foo foo foo\r\n" + 
        "<a href=\"foo.com\">Foo site</a>\r\n" + 
        "Bar bar bar\r\n" + 
        "<a href=\"bar.org\">Bar site</a>\r\n" + 
        "bla bla bla\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "";
```

Here is a small test:

```
@Test
public void replaceLinks() {
    String regex = "<a href=\".*(foo\\.com|bar\\.org).*\">[^<]+</a>";
    String output = input.replaceAll(regex, "<a href=\"myweb.com\">my web</a>");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

The output is:

```
my text
Foo foo foo
<a href="myweb.com">my web</a>
Bar bar bar
<a href="myweb.com">my web</a>
bla bla bla
```

However, since your input seems to be a HTML fragement the proper way is to parse it with a HTML parser like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) and get all the links then apply the pattern to the `href` attribute. If it matches then do the replacement by setting the new link into the element.

Write the fragment bak when your done.

```
@Test
public void replaceLinksJSoup() {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
    Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(foo\\.com|bar\\.org).*");
    for (Element link : links) {
        String linkHref = link.attr("href");
        if (pattern.matcher(linkHref).matches()) {
            link.attr("href", "myweb.com");
            link.text("my web");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(doc.body().html());
}
```

Output:

```
my text Foo foo foo 
<a href="myweb.com">my web</a> Bar bar bar 
<a href="myweb.com">my web</a> bla bla bla
```